# is it possible to export the search data into a csv file

Tags: php, mysql, search, export-to-csv

i m working on php with mysql and there is a search form in my site by which a user can search by name and location from mysql database.so i have a table in database named customers which have 5 fields name, enail,mobile,address and location.when a user search the result appear in table format.now i want to export this result in csv format.is it possible??

Here is my search form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" name="userform">
    <?php if($_GET[id]){?>
    <?php }else{?>
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Search</legend>
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Search Term</label>
    <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" class="span3 search-query" name="term" placeholder="search by name and location">
    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="search">Search</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and Here is the query to fetch the result from databse:

```
<?php 
                 // to print the records
                $term = $_POST['term'];
                if($term != ""){
                 $sql = mysql_query("select * from customers where name like '%$term%' or location like '%$term%'");
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                ?>

                <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row[cid];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[name ];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[email];?></td>
                <!--<td>&nbsp;</td>-->
                <td><?php echo $row[mobile];?></td>               
                <td><?php echo $row[address];?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row[location];?></td>
?>
```

Comment: yes it is possible. you can try it with PHPExcel http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you query the result again like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM customers
WHERE name LIKE '%" . $term . "%'
OR location LIKE '%" . $term . "%'";
```

Haven't tried this yet, but this should generate a csv file you can then open or link to.

Comment: it doesn't work for me...:( this query doesnt showing anything neither the result data in my table format nor the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel has already been suggested and I concur, this is one of the best libraries out there. One major drawback is its memory footprint, and it could be an overkill for a simple CSV export.

If you only need CSV, you may want to look into the (more low-level) built-in feature of MySQL: [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html).

It is less flexible and has a few pitfalls, but its is lightning fast compared to resorting to an external library. Most problems you may encounter with this approach have already been answered here at StackOverflow.